# pytorch affine_grid: what is the order of affine transformations?

Tags: pytorch

I want to use Pytorch's `affine_grid` to sample an image. I want to rotate an image at 30-degree intervals and add a translation on top of the rotation. I built the rotation matrix and set all the translation terms to `(-0.5,0)`, but I got this strange result. It looks like the image was first shifted and then rotated. Therefore, I would like to ask whether `affine_grid` would translate or rotate the image first.

Here are my results:
[image]

Here are my transformation matrices:

[image]